InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'CourseAPIController' while activating 'CoursePageController'
I am working on a small ASP.NET Core MVC / Web API application for managing courses in a school database. The project uses ASP.NET Core MVC, MySQL, and Entity Framework Core for the backend.
The app has two controllers:

CourseAPIController – an API controller that handles CRUD operations for courses.
CoursePageController – an MVC controller that uses CourseAPIController to fetch or manipulate data for the frontend views.

Here's a simplified version of my CoursePageController:
public class CoursePageController : Controller
{
    private readonly CourseAPIController _api;

    public CoursePageController(CourseAPIController api)
    {
        _api = api;
    }

    public IActionResult List(string SearchKey = null)
    {
        var courses = _api.ListCourses(SearchKey);
        return View(courses);
    }
}

When I run the application, I get the following error:

InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Cumulative_assignment.Models.CourseAPIController' while attempting to activate 'Cumulative_assignment.Controllers.CoursePageController'.

I understand this is related to dependency injection, but I'm not sure how to correctly set it up for this scenario.
Checking if the constructor injection in CoursePageController is causing issues.
Making CourseAPIController methods static (but I'd prefer to stick with DI to make it extensible).

The issue you are facing might be because the CourseAPIController hasn't been properly registered in the Dependency Injection (DI) container, or you may be requesting an incorrect type of instance of the dependency. To resolve this issue, you need to register CourseAPIController in the DI container. You can do this by adding the following line to your Program.cs :
builder.Services.AddScoped<CourseAPIController>(); Make sure that the registration of services is done before any controller actions are called.

By default controllers are not registered in the DI container. And usually you should not register them there, if you have some common logic you want to share between controllers then move it in some separate class (and register it in the DI and resolve in both controllers).
But for completeness (and as a quick fix for your code) you can register controllers in the DI container with AddControllersAsServices:
builder.Services
    .AddControllers()
    .AddControllersAsServices();

